# To perform Autosuggestion using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Having some problem in selecting the option from the dropdown using autosuggestion. Please give a solution to select the option.

The related code is posted below :-

```
@Test(priority = 4)
public void ReportType() throws InterruptedException {
 WebElement reporttype = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[3]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/span/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/span/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[1]"));
 reporttype.clear();
 reporttype.sendKeys("NMQ De");
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[3]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/span/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/span/div/ul/li[4]")));
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[3]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/span/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/span/div/ul/li[4]")).click();
}
```

Comment: You need to post your HTML code of dropdown and it's related parents ..

Comment: We cannot help you without an HTML example

Comment: <li class="DropDownAjaxAlternateListItem DropDownAjaxSelectedListItem" onclick="$find('ctl00_cph1_ddlReportType')._onListClick('16', 'NMQ Details');" onmouseout="Sys.UI.DomElement.toggleCssClass(this,'DropDownAjaxSelectedListItem');" onmouseover="Sys.UI.DomElement.toggleCssClass(this,'DropDownAjaxSelectedListItem');" style="cursor: pointer; list-style: outside none none; height: 18px; width: 330px;" internalvalue="16">

Answer (score 0):

Think your question as google search when u do some google search google provides u auto suggestion

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String textToSelect = "headlines today";

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
Thread.sleep(2000);
WebElement autoOptions= driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
autoOptions.sendKeys("he");

List<WebElement> optionsToSelect = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='sbqs_c']"));

for(WebElement option : optionsToSelect){
    System.out.println(option);
    if(option.getText().equals(textToSelect)) {
        System.out.println("Trying to select: "+textToSelect);
        option.click();
        break;
    }
}
```